# Does Random Sampling Affect Significance of Regression Result?

Tags: sampling, p-value, treatment-effect

When a research design includes treatment and control group and the number of samples in the treatment group far exceeds that in the control group due to the nature of a data set, the treatment effect from a regression result becomes not significant.

I wanted to do a bit of experiment here by randomly sampling the treatment group side so that the number of treated samples reduces to a reasonable numbers that are comparable to the control group. After running the same regression, treatment effect becomes significant.

What would be the underlying reason that generates such a difference? Is this because the distribution of the treatment group became more randomly distributed?

I would try a matching algorithm such as Propensity Score Matching (PSM) instead, but there are not matching covariates between treatment and control group due to the nature of the limited data availability.

I wonder random sampling makes sense as the other option. Some experted knowledge would be very appreciated.

Comment: That strategy of undersampling the treatment data seems to me likely to increase both Type I and Type II errors (in this case a Type I error).  If you repeat the exercise with different samples do you get the significant result every time, most of the time or a few times?

Answer (score 0):

> When a research design includes treatment and control group and the number of samples in the treatment group far exceeds that in the control group due to the nature of a data set, the treatment effect from a regression result becomes not significant.

I don't think this is necessarily true. For example, let's see what happens when we simulate a dataset that has 20x more samples in treatment than in control:

```r
set.seed(1234)
N_control <- 500
N_treatment <- 10000
x <- rep(c(0, 1), c(N_control, N_treatment))
b <- 0.7
y <- 20 + b * x + rnorm(n = N_control + N_treatment)

summary(lm(y ~ x))
```

The output is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3979 -0.6691 -0.0013  0.6645  3.6118 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 20.00184    0.04424  452.13   <2e-16 ***
x            0.70446    0.04533   15.54   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9892 on 10498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02249,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02239 
F-statistic: 241.5 on 1 and 10498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The model recovers the true treatment effect ($b=0.7$) with a p-value that is extremely close to 0.